# HttpClient, HTTP/2 and client certificates .pfx, .p12

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi

How to re-write this piece of c# code in .Net Core >= 1.0

I have read that HttpClient does not support 
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4479

---

### .Net Framework 4.5 version

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(this.endPoint) as HttpWebRequest;
request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF8";
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(this.certFileName);
request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

string result = null;
using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

---

### Solution:- .Net Core Version

Finally managed to get it working, Though had to change certificate from .p12 to .pfx (private key + SSL cert). It doesn't work with .p12.

```
    private FormUrlEncodedContent GetLoginBodyAsContent(string username, string password)
    {
        var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username));
        postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password));
        return new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
    }

    private async Task<LoginResponse> Login(string username, string password, string certFilename)
    {
        var clientHandler = GetClientHandler();

        var handler = AddCert(clientHandler, certFilename);
        var client = InitHttpClientInstance(handler, this.AppKey);

        var content = GetLoginBodyAsContent(username, password);

        var result = await client.PostAsync("/api/certlogin", content);
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var jsonSerialiser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(LoginResponse));
        var stream = new MemoryStream(await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
        var response = (LoginResponse)jsonSerialiser.ReadObject(stream);
        return response;
    }
    private HttpClientHandler AddCert(HttpClientHandler clientHandler, string certFilename)
    {
        var certPfx = new X509Certificate2(certFilename);
        clientHandler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
        clientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
        clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(certPfx);

        clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += 
            (HttpRequestMessage req, X509Certificate2 cert2, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors err) => { return true; };

        return clientHandler;
    }
    private HttpClient InitHttpClientInstance(HttpMessageHandler clientHandler, string appKey, string baseUrl = DefaultAuthServiceUrl)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Application", appKey);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = true;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Close");

        return client;
    }
    private HttpClientHandler GetClientHandler()
    {
        var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        return clientHandler;
    }
```

Seems .net core is meant to make life difficult.. too much boilerplate, easy to get it wrong.

Comment: Try it. The issue you link to isn't relevant. It's about Windows UWP apps.

Comment: did you try, it does not even compile with .net Core.  CS1061 'HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'ClientCertificates' and no extension method.....

Comment: *You* have to provide a full problem description including any compilation errors. You linked to an invalid issue. It isn't clear from your question that you actually tried - it sounds as if you found and issue and stopped trying

Comment: The linked issue is about *HttpClient* too, not HttpWebRequest. Did you try with HttpClient? Why are you using HttpWebRequest ?

Comment: How to re-write this piece of c# code?  should make it clear IMHO.

Comment: A relevant *closed* [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11036) shows that HttpClient does support client certificates. You can use `HttpClientHandler.ClientCertificates` to add a client certificate